# iOS App is not being relaunched when receiving push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-notifications

I'm having trouble with Firebase push notifications. I'm currently using a physical iPhone with iOS 12.3.1, and I've managed to receive notifications when the application is in foreground or background mode.

When it's in foreground, method `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets triggered and I can parse the notification contents to store it in CoreData.

Also when it's in the background (but not killed) `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets called and I can parse the contents too.

The problem appears when user kills the app from the recents screen. As fas as I know, application handles received notifications by calling `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method, but only in foreground and background modes.

When applications is killed, it can be re-launched by system if notification body contains the `content_available: true` key, and then `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method should be called with the notification contents inside the `launchOptions` dictionary.

I can't get `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` called when application is killed. I've already enabled background fetch and remote notifications capabilites.

I can also parse the notification if I click the notification when it's received (also when app is killed), but I need to trigger `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to parse the notification and store it in app notification history, because if user deletes the notification without opening it, it will be lost.

I've done a lot of research through official documentation and this site, but none of the methods I tried worked for me.

Do you know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475317/5084797

Comment: Thank you for your reply @manishsharma93 . Unfortunately i've not managed to get it working. I'll investigate.