# get List of All Push Notification While App is Closed iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications

I have this requirement where I need to store (Save some information of Notification in Plist file) from Remote Notifications **even if my app is closed**.

I have done some research, I found some links which say I need to use PushKit, but is used only for VoIP Based app, my app is just Data Processing or Analytics related app.

I found Notification Service Extension used along with App Group, one such link is [Mobile Messaging SDK](https://github.com/infobip/mobile-messaging-sdk-ios) But it is paid SDK.
Please Friends I know there are many geeks out there on SO, I need your help at the earliest possible. I am sure you guys will help Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application . And make sure that you add Background Modes under Signing & Capabilities and check Remote notifications so your app can wake up if it was suspended

Comment: read this
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-notification-service-extensions--cms-27550

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475317/5084797